# How to access JTextArea from a class to another class

Tags: java

I want to access status so I can append values to it but my code doesn't seem to work. Please help me.

```
public class NewClient extends JFrame implements ActionListener{


private static final int WIDTH = 600;
private static final int HEIGHT = 400;
public static JTextArea chat, event, cwindow, c2window, type, status;

public NewClient(){

    status = new JTextArea(30,10);
    status.setEditable(false);
}
```

Here's the other class

```
public class NewServer{


public static NewClient client;

public static void main(String args[]){
       client.status.append("Online");
}
```

Comment: You never instantiated `client`. You should actually be calling `status.append` in a `static` manner rather than reference it through an instance stored in a variable. Finally, you need to post all your Swing code to the `EventQueue`, using `EventQueue.invokeLater(Runnable)`, to be executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Answer (score 0):

There two things to note here:

> You have to create object to invoke its constructor, otherwise you
>   will hit NullPointerException in the following line

```
client.status.append("Online");
```

So, the fix is to create an object and assign value:

```
client = new NewClient();
client.status.append("Online");
```

> Static variables like `status` need not be invoked through object. So,
>   instead of assigning value like the following:

```
client.status.append("Online");
```

You can directly invoke the variable using class name:

```
client = new NewClient();   
NewClient.status.append("Online");
```

If you note above, we created new object for `NewClient` so that the value for `status` text area is initialized as part of `NewClient`'s constructor.